# Xpath find node with children or grandchildren that contains attribute and text value

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to parse a website with the following structure:

```
<div class='MarketGroup'>
  <div class='MarketGroup_GroupName'>
     <div class='MarketGroup_Name'>Partido</div>
```

If you click on the first div item a dropdown menu appears, so I want to find that div item, which has a children or (in this case) a grandchild with an attribute "MarketGroup Name" and text value "Partido".

My python code is as follows:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//div[.//*[@class="MarketGroup_Name and contains(.,"Partido")]]')
```

But I get an error because apparently my syntax is not a valid xpath expression.
So, what is a valid xpath expression for this?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error in your XPath,

```
//div[.//*[@class="MarketGroup_Name and contains(.,"Partido")]]
                                   ^
```

is due to a missing close `"`.

Other than that, your XPath appears to specify what you want, but you might clean it up a bit:

```
//div[.//div[@class="MarketGroup_Name" and .="Partido"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Returns any `MarketGroup` that has a descendant `MarketGroup_Name` with text *"Partido"*.

> //div[@class="MarketGroup" and descendant::div[@class="MarketGroup_Name" and contains(text(),"Partido")]]

Answer (score -1):

Your xpath is missing a ", as is mentioned by other answer. But the fixed one can find two element: `<div class='MarketGroup'>` and `<div class='MarketGroup_GroupName'>`, this may not what you want. I guess you may want the one which class is MarketGroup, so the result xpath is:

```
//div[@class="MarketGroup"][.//div[@class="MarketGroup_Name" and text()="Partido"]]
```

If you cannot find elements using above xpath, it may due to the xmlns. Using this one:

```
//*[local-name()="div" and @class="MarketGroup"][.//*[local-name()="div" and @class="MarketGroup_Name" and text()="Partido"]]
```